# JQuery Tools validator Customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, jquery-tools

I use this function to work arrounds with JQuery tools for validation of my fields. So that it can also check **select tags**. It work fine for me. Now the thing is that it display  error message(tootips comenext to feild) but once i fix it. It didn't immediately make error(tootips comenext to feild) disappear the way it do for **input tags**  onChange event or onBlur. In short i want handle event and message visibility by myself for some fields like select.

$.tools.validator.fn(".select .required", 
                 function(input, value) {
             return value.length >= 1 ? true : {
        en: "Please select this Mandatory field"};
});

Comment: Please edit your question and correct your code formatting, I've tried it myself but I can't tell if it's a formatting or a coding mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Its Seems that tooltips disappear on keydown event.. Well i make it invisible by handling an event of onfail of validator of JQuery Tools